# What is the equation to get P-Q in Montgomery curve XZ coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves, elliptic-curve-generation, montgomery-ladder

[image]

Based on Differentia-addition on P I can understand `(Xp,Zp)` which is the base point, `(Xq,Zq)` which comes from Doubling, but I don't know what is the equation used to get `P-Q` to get X-,Z-.

So for example if I have `P1(8,3,1)` so it means  `(X⊖,Z⊖) = (8,1)` and the value of `(Xq,Zq)` is from doubling? what about (Xp,Zp)?

Comment: Does the text I added to the question address your concern?  Or, are you looking to use differential addition in a context other than the Montgomery Ladder?

Comment: Actually I am looking for deferential Addition in Montgomery curve https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know what is the equation used to get `P-Q` to get X-,Z-.

Actually, if you're using the Montgomery Ladder algorithm, it's the base point we're multiplying.

At each step of the iteration, we have the points $P, P+G, G$ (where $P = zG$, where $z$ is the part of the multiplier we've already entered), and depending on whether the next bit in the multiplier is a 1, we want (if it is a 0) $2P, 2P+G, G$ or (if it is a 1) $2P+G, 2P+2G, G$.

So, the first step is to take $(X_P, Z_P) = P+G$, and $(X_Q, Z_Q) = P$, and $(X_\ominus, Z_\ominus ) = G$; it is easy to see that the precondition $(X_P, Z_P) - (X_Q, Z_Q) = (X_\ominus, Z_\ominus )$ holds; the addition algorithm then gives us $(X_\oplus, Z_\oplus ) = (X_P, Z_P) + (X_Q, Z_Q) = 2P+G$.  And, all we need to do is compute either $2P$ or $2P+2G$ - either case is just a doubling of a value we already have.

And, to start the process, we start with $P=0$ (hence our triple is $(0, G, G)$, which fulfills the precondition, and then we can start by shifting the multiplier bits in, in msb to lsb order...

Hence, in this application, $X_\ominus, Z_\ominus )$ is always $G$ (the base point we are multiplying by).

Comment: Actually I am using Montgomery curve differential addition and want to know what is the equation used to get the value of  (X⊖,Z⊖) ?

Comment: @CiscoSaeed: so, you have $(X_\oplus, Z_\oplus)$, and want to know how to get $(X_\ominus, Z_\ominus)$?

Comment: the issue is how to get (X⊖,Z⊖) to use it in equation without calculation (X⊕,Z⊕)

Comment: @CiscoSaeed: If you're just given $(X_P, Z_P), (X_Q, Z_Q)$, you can't.  The representation of the points $P, Q$ are missing the $y$ coordinates, that is, the sign information, and so there's nothing distinguishing $P-Q$ from $P+Q$, that is $(X_\ominus, Z_\ominus)$  from $(X_\oplus, Z_\oplus)$.  While you could devise a procedure to compute both, there would be no way to know which is which.

Comment: But i don't understand as in paper to use it incase to reduce multiplication so if i used addition so what is the difference? And what is the addition equation?

Comment: @CiscoSaeed: I'm sorry, but I cannot parse your question.  Might I ask what application you intend to use differential addition for?

Comment: I am trying to apply this https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom-xz.html to see how does it work? I don't understand How to use (X⊖,Z⊖) without addition!

Comment: I edited the question to make it easy to parse the question.

Comment: so based on your solution edited, the (XP,ZP) is (0,0) and (XQ,ZQ) is (8,1) and (X⊖,Z⊖) is (8,1) if I considered the G point is (8,3,1)?

Comment: @CiscoSaeed: well, yes, at least, for the initial iteration of the Montgomery ladder

Comment: thanks, but I need to understand if I want to double then do add so doubled `P(8,3,1)` then get `(6,3)` then if I want to do addition then the values will be like this order (XP,ZP) is (6,3) and (XQ,ZQ) is (8,1) and (X⊖,Z⊖) is (8,1)  ?